# Investigating Javascript Memory Leaks

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, html5-canvas, game-engine

I recently encountered a memory leak with my html5 canvas game engine, the process can end up using 5+ GB ram.

I looked at the developer tools in chrome and tried to nail it down to no avail.

How does one go about investigating memory leaks in HTML5 javascript, perhaps specifically when it comes to canvas?

Thanks again.

Comment: You expect people to look through 2k lines of code?

Comment: -1. please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I don't expect anything, no.

Comment: I have rewritten the post. I actually didn't mean to ask "please review my entire 2k lines of code" I merely included it for informational purposes.

Comment: Well, profiling the code with the developer tools is one way. I don't think the memory consumption comes from the canvas itself, but rather how you are drawing to the canvas, i.e. by the objects you create in this process. 5GB sounds like a lot though, I would expect the page to crash much earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in Chromium under ubuntu, linux.

Comment: I don't feel this deserved to get downvoted. Thanks for following up with the answer, Petter.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much nailed it: Use Google Chrome's profiling tool. Make sure you select the Memory profile as a starting point.

The biggest cause for memory leaks is within closures - so that's another place to look.